# How to show child route with module in BottomNavigation in NativeScript Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, bottomnavigationview, nativescript-angular

I am trying to load child module i.e HomeModule into BottomNavigation page-router-outlet and trying to use router-outlet of home.component.html as a parent of orderComponent.

So in conclude:

1. Lazy loading page.module into app component through page-router-outlet
2. Lazy loading homeModule into page component through BottomNavigation Page-router-outlet
3. Finally trying to load OrderComponent into HomeComponent by angular router-outlet

**app.component.html**

```
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.component.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/pages/default", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
    { 
        path: "pages",
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
        .then(m => m.PagesModule) 
    },
];
```

**page-router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "default", component: PagesComponent, children: [
            { 
                path: "home",
                loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomeModule),
                component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                outlet: 'homeOutlet'
            },
            { 
                path: "account",
                loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then( m => m.AccountModule),
                component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
                outlet: 'accountOutlet'
            },
        ]
    },
    
];
```

**pages.component.html**

```
<TabStrip>
    <TabStripItem>
        <Label text="Home"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf015;" class="fas"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>

    <TabStripItem class="special">
        <Label text="Account"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf007;" class="fas"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
</TabStrip>

<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Page-router-outlet name="homeOutlet"></Page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <Page-router-outlet name="accountOutlet"></Page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { OrdersComponent } from "./orders/orders.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
        { path: 'orders', component: OrdersComponent}
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Home"></Label>
    <Button text="Tap me" (tap)="tapMe()"></Button>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to do something like this in your `pages.component.ts` `ngOnInit()`:

```
this._routerExtensions.navigate(
            [{
                outlets: {
                    homeOutlet: ["home"],
                    accountOutlet: ["account"]
                }
            }],
            { relativeTo: this._activatedRoute }
        );
```

I have a similar structured app as yours and this is the only difference I see.

If the tab is showing selected but the page is white, then it is likely just a routing issue.

Be careful with nested routes because of differences like `navigate()` doesn't use relative path but something like `routerLink` does.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for your answer, code is already available on pages.component.ts, still getting blank page.